# Group date column into n-day periods

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, date, pandas-groupby

I need a function that groups date column into n-day periods with respect to some start and end dates (1 year interval). To assign a quarter (~90 day period) to every date in the data frame I used the code below, which is not very neat (and I want to reuse it for 30-day period as well)

```
def get_quarter(row, start_date, col_name):
#     date = row['TRN_DT']
    date = row[col_name]
    if date >= start_date and date <= start_date + timedelta(days = 90):
        return 0
    if date > start_date + timedelta(days = 90) and date <= start_date + timedelta(180):
        return 1
    if date > start_date + timedelta(180) and date <= start_date + timedelta(270):
        return 2
    return 3
```

It basically checks row by row which interval current date belongs to. I was wondering whether there is a better way to do this. pandas.Series.dt.to_period() will not do since it uses a calendar year as a reference --start 01.Jan, end 31.Dec; that is, 16.Jan.XXXX will always be in Q1; what I want is for 16.Jan to be in Q3 if the start date is 16-Jun. Thanks

Comment: Could this work for you? Substract the start_date for every date record, and then use the pandas methods (like `to_period`)

Comment: good idea, thanks! I did start_date - 01-Jan of the same year as start_date, subtracted this difference from every date record, and applied dt.to_period()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTR, a possible solution is to shift every date in the series according to the `start_date`, to simulate that `start_date` is the beginning of the year:

```
>>> start_date = pd.to_datetime("2021-06-16")
>>> dates_series = pd.Series([pd.to_datetime("2020-01-16"), pd.to_datetime("2020-04-16")], name="dates")
0    1
1    2
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```

We calculate the difference between the current date and the beginning of the same year.

```
>>> offset = start_date - start_date.replace(month=1, day=1)
>>> offset
166 days 00:00:00
```

We move all of our dates by the same offser to calculate the "new quarter"

```
>>> (dates - offset).dt.quarter
0    3
1    4
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```